# Are batch commits an efficient strategy?

Tags: java, sql-server, transactions, blocking

I'm adding batch-sql-commits an application (With an MS SQL Server remote database) that once used db-connections with auto-commit. I'm wondering if now that auto-commit = false, and I make e.g. 10 sql-updates to the connection before making a commit, what kind of blocking can I expect from the update, as opposed to the commit? Is this an efficient strategy?

The db connection is using the default isolation-level: READ COMMITTED.

```
Connection connection = getConn();
while (true) {
  makeSqlUpdate(connection); // how will this block?
  if (batchCount++ >= 10) {
      connection.commit();  // I know this will block for the atomic update of the db.
      batchCount = 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: Not doing auto commit is a good move from performance side. You need to do put in place addBatch/executeBatch logic (if not implemented) to get further performance improvement. You can commit after some number of updates or at the end, answer depends of DB type you use and need to do complete rollback and how long update transaction should last (ex: if there are changes in parallel). NOTE: Condition with batchCount starts to commit on *each* number >= 10 in your example...

Comment: @igr, added batchCount reset. Also this is MS SQL Server. The DB isolation level is default. READ COMMITTED.

Comment: Your batchCount would have more impact on performance if done for executeBatch logic. You can do executeBatch along with commit if you prefer. Or commit after some bigger number of executions, pick what makes more sense in your situation. Currently 10 is very low number. I would start with 100-200 batch size for executeBatch and leave commit for the end if small-medium table. Test also bigger batch size, ex:  until 2000 or 5000 value by batch execution and commit as preferred if table is bigger and see where you get best compromise between performance and resource usage.

Comment: Batching 10 commits together might be faster than doing individual commits, but it's worth trying different, larger numbers (100, 1000, etc.) to see how performance changes. For example, it's possible that you don't observe much difference going from 1 to 10 at a time, but maybe you find a more meaningful increase in performance when going to 100 (or more) at a time.

Comment: Despite the literal *10*, this is an abstract example. It could be 1K or 1M, etc. The question is more about the overhead with the transaction-based-update (or an insert) vs the commit. You both seem to be implying that this batched method is more performant, but how much?

Comment: In general it probably will help, but “how much” depends on the SQL, the database, indexes, total row count, read/write traffic during your commits, etc.